# WebBrowser css not loaded

Tags: winapi, webbrowser-control, iwebbrowser2, pluggableprotocol

I have a complex HTML5 based user interface, which I show in my native win32 desktop application using webbrowser (Internet Explorer).

I've decided to open it from local machine instead of web server. But it did not work due to various security restrictions. So I found a workaround: setup asynchronous pluggable protocol for https protocol inside of my process and just provide data from local machine instead of Internet. I had to also implement my custom `IInternetSecurityManager` for the things to work (for unknown reason it was not enough to just implement `IInternetSecurityManager` and use `file:` scheme).

Now all seems to work fine except the one thing: browser completely ignores `CSS` files. It acts the way as if files are not there. It loads `js` from files, shows images, but does not "see" `CSS` files.

If I try to navigate to `CSS` file, it shows me this error message:
[image]

But if I try to access this `CSS` file using `XMLHttpRequest` - it "downloads" it fine.

Sorry for not providing a minimal reproducible example - it would be quite hard. Maybe somebody knows the reason, or can suggest me anything that I could try to resolve this issue?

Comment: Are you using MFC?

Comment: Can you post some code?